# What's the fastest way to update a scatterplot?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I have a dashboard that is very similar to this-

```
import datetime

import dash
from dash import dcc, html
import plotly
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

# pip install pyorbital
from pyorbital.orbital import Orbital
satellite = Orbital('TERRA')

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
app.layout = html.Div(
    html.Div([
        html.H4('TERRA Satellite Live Feed'),
        html.Div(id='live-update-text'),
        dcc.Graph(id='live-update-graph'),
        dcc.Interval(
            id='interval-component',
            interval=1*1000, # in milliseconds
            n_intervals=0
        )
    ])
)


@app.callback(Output('live-update-text', 'children'),
              Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals'))
def update_metrics(n):
    lon, lat, alt = satellite.get_lonlatalt(datetime.datetime.now())
    style = {'padding': '5px', 'fontSize': '16px'}
    return [
        html.Span('Longitude: {0:.2f}'.format(lon), style=style),
        html.Span('Latitude: {0:.2f}'.format(lat), style=style),
        html.Span('Altitude: {0:0.2f}'.format(alt), style=style)
    ]


# Multiple components can update everytime interval gets fired.
@app.callback(Output('live-update-graph', 'figure'),
              Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals'))
def update_graph_live(n):
    satellite = Orbital('TERRA')
    data = {
        'time': [],
        'Latitude': [],
        'Longitude': [],
        'Altitude': []
    }

    # Collect some data
    for i in range(180):
        time = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(seconds=i*20)
        lon, lat, alt = satellite.get_lonlatalt(
            time
        )
        data['Longitude'].append(lon)
        data['Latitude'].append(lat)
        data['Altitude'].append(alt)
        data['time'].append(time)

    # Create the graph with subplots
    fig = plotly.tools.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, vertical_spacing=0.2)
    fig['layout']['margin'] = {
        'l': 30, 'r': 10, 'b': 30, 't': 10
    }
    fig['layout']['legend'] = {'x': 0, 'y': 1, 'xanchor': 'left'}

    fig.append_trace({
        'x': data['time'],
        'y': data['Altitude'],
        'name': 'Altitude',
        'mode': 'lines+markers',
        'type': 'scatter'
    }, 1, 1)
    fig.append_trace({
        'x': data['Longitude'],
        'y': data['Latitude'],
        'text': data['time'],
        'name': 'Longitude vs Latitude',
        'mode': 'lines+markers',
        'type': 'scatter'
    }, 2, 1)

    return fig


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

I want to update a single scatterplot. The scatterplot has about twenty-thousand data points. Right now this is my code:

```
fig['data'][1]['x'] = dataframe_with_new_data['measure_x']
fig['data'][1]['y'] = dataframe_with_new_data['measure_y']
```

There are only a couple hundred new data points every time the chart updates. I am concerned that it might be slower to replace the entire x and y entries in the `fig` object, but I'm not sure what a faster alternative might look like.

This is sample data with five hundred points:

```
import random

x = range(0, 10000, 20)
y = random.sample(range(10, 30000), 500)
```

Comment: Do you have some sample data (not 20000 points) you could share?

Comment: I added some data

Comment: For some reason I have this error `HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden` on this line satellite = Orbital('TERRA')

Comment: I will try to help you with another data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `extendData` property of graph to add data to an existing graph without building the graph from scratch every time the interveral triggers. As written in the [documentation](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/graph):

> extendData (list | dict; optional): Data that should be appended to
> existing traces. Has the form [updateData, traceIndices, maxPoints],
> where updateData is an object containing the data to extend,
> traceIndices (optional) is an array of trace indices that should be
> extended, and maxPoints (optional) is either an integer defining the
> maximum number of points allowed or an object with key:value pairs
> matching updateData

I selected the time interval 100 ms to show how fast it is to plot the points without any delay.

```
import dash
from dash import *
import plotly
import numpy as np 



external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']


app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div(
    html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(id='live-update-graph', figure = dict(
                data=[{'x': [0],
                       'y': [0],
                       'name': 'Altitude',
                        'mode': 'lines+markers',
                        'type': 'scatter'
                       }]
            )),
        dcc.Interval(
            id='interval-component',
            interval=100, # in milliseconds
            n_intervals=0
        )
    ])
)


@app.callback(Output('live-update-graph', 'extendData'),
              Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals'),
              [State('live-update-graph', 'figure')])
def update_graph_live(n, existing):
    
    data = {
        'time': [],
        'Altitude': []
    }

    # Collect some data
    
    time = existing['data'][0]['x'][-1] + 1 
    alt = np.random.random()

    return dict(x=[[time]], y=[[alt]])

    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: Can I use this to update other parts of a trace, such as the text?

Comment: @Hamzah, Yes, you can do it by adding layout inside the figure `dcc.Graph(id='live-update-graph', 
 figure = dict(data=[],layout=[])`

Comment: I don't understand, what part in that example do you update the text?

Comment: What do you mean by text? do you mean the text of the title?

Comment: I mean like text labels on a bar chart, for example

Comment: Labels of what xaxis and yaxis?

Comment: Like the text = argument in the add.trace() function, for example the value on each bar shows up as text on the bar

Comment: You can replace data = [...] with `data=[go.Bar(x=x, y=y, text=y, textposition='auto',)]`